# AJAX-enabled form will only submit once using AJAX, then defaults to HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

AJAX-enabled form will only submit once using AJAX, then defaults to using a standard HTTP request. Code is below:

```
    $('#urlContainer form').submit(function(){

        var p = {};
        p['url'] = $('input#url').val();

        if($('#urlContainer #results').length != 0){
            $('#urlContainer #results').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $('#urlContainer').load(location.href+' #urlContainer>*',p,function(){
                    $('#urlContainer #results').hide();
                    $('#urlContainer #results').fadeIn(1000);

                });
            });
        } else {
            $('#urlContainer').load(location.href+' #urlContainer>*',p,function(){
                $('#urlContainer #results').hide();
                $('#urlContainer #results').fadeIn(1000);

            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the form inside urlContainer?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the selectors so they're more specific. Should be easier to understand now.

Comment: where's the code for refreshDashboardTable()?

Comment: It's irrelevant to the problem. Removed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function replaces the contents of the matched elements with the result of the AJAX call. When that happens, the form that you are binding to is removed (or replaced), so the original event handler does not trigger.

If you use `.live('submit' ...)` instead of `.submit`, it should resolve your issue:

```
$('#urlContainer form').live('submit', function(){
    ...
});
```

The `live` method attaches to current *and future* elements that match the selector.

Comment: @tommizzle FWIW, you can improve the performance of this by doing `$('form', '#urlContainer')` as your selector, which is equivalent to the code in my answer.

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks! Do you know where I can find some documentation on this method?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#urlContainer').load(...)
```

This code replaces all the content within `#urlContainer`.  All the elements are replaced, which means that all event handlers bound to them will also be replaced.  You should use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to run code for events on elements that may not exist yet:

```
$('#urlContainer').delegate('form', 'submit', function(){
    // the code from your submit handler
});
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite your code to avoid obliterating the `form` element, so the handler on it would persist.